# Is there a way to trace callstack of an application running on gem5?

Tags: c, debugging, simulation, callstack, gem5

I am looking for a way to keep a track of all the functions that are called when I run an application on the gem5 simulator. For example, there is this code **test.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fp;
    char c[] = "hello";
    char buffer[100];
    fp = fopen("Working.txt", "w+");
    fwrite(c, 1, 5, fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, 1, 5, fp);
    printf("%s \n",buffer);
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

I compiled it to a binary and I basically want to track all the functions that are called when I use `fopen, fwrite, fseek, fread, printf, fclose, and return`.

Taking `fread` as an example, if `fread() -> foo() -> bar() -> bar2() ... -> do_syscall_64()`, is the function call flow that calls the syscall in the end I want to track all of those functions.

I have already tried using gem5's debug mode using the `--debug-flags` option (eg. command: `build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=Stack --debug-file=test_Stack.out configs/example/se.py --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --caches --mem-type=DDR4_2400_8x8 --mem-size=8GB --cmd=./test`) and tried a bunch of flags including `SyscallAll`, `Stack`, and `StackDist`.

While the `SyscallAll` Flag just prints the syscalls that are being called at tick N, the other two debug flags print nothing at all.

Am I doing something wrong there? Is there even a way to print the user call stack inside gem5? Or can I do a custom implementation? Any help is appreciated.